# Why can't I get values from depth texture using FBO?

Tags: opengl

I can't get depth values from FBO's depth texture.. Program's workflow is like below :

Setup
1. Make pass1 FBO (color texture + depth texture)
2. Make pass2 RBO (color renderbuffer + depth renderbuffer)

Rendering
1. only vertex processing (pass1)
2. get depth values from pass0 FBO's depth texture
3. vertex and fragment processing using a previous depth values

Setup.1 code (create pass0 fbo)

```
glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
glGenTextures(2, &pass1_tex);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, pass1_tex[0]);
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_RGBA8, w, h, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, 0);
glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE1);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, pass1_tex[1]);
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT, w, h, 0, GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT, 0);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_COMPARE_MODE, GL_COMPARE_R_TO_TEXTURE);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_COMPARE_FUNC, GL_LEQUAL);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_DEPTH_TEXTURE_MODE, GL_INTENSITY);
glGenFramebuffers(1, pass1_fbo);
glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, pass1_fbo);
glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMEMNT0, GL_TEXTURE_2D< pass1_tex[0], 0);
glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_DEPTH_ATTACHMEMNT, GL_TEXTURE_2D< pass1_tex[0], 0);
```

And to get depth values in rendering, I did like below :

```
glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, pass1_fbo);
// vertex processing..
glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE1);
glGetTexImage(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT, GL_FLOAT, &debug_buf[0]);
```

But, there are only 1.0 or 0.0 in debug_buf array. Of course, all objects are between 1.0 and -1.0 distance (NDC), a near and far value is 1.0 and 2.0 in gluPerspective().

Why can't I get proper depth values from FBO's depth texture?

Comment: Um, could you post code that actually compiles? `glBindFramebuffer` binds the framebuffer to the context; it only takes two parameters. Also, if that was supposed to be `glFramebufferTexture`, you put the same texture as both the color and depth, which I'm pretty sure is not legal. Are you checking framebuffer completeness? Lastly, you never bound the depth texture when you tried to call `glGetTexImage`

Comment: The depth buffer will always have a value range from [-1.0 .. 1.0], regardless of the near and far values (at least as long as near < far and both are reasonable). That's what normalizing does here.

Answer (score 2):

You can find the answer to your problem [in this article](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Texture). When using GL_COMPARE_R_TO_TEXTURE, sampling the depth texture returns a comparison result of the depth texture values against a reference value (which is the interpolated r texture coordinate). What you want to do is to specify the following texture parameters instead:

```
glTexParameteri (GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_COMPARE_MODE, GL_NONE);
glTexParameteri (GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_DEPTH_TEXTURE_MODE, GL_INTENSITY);
```

Comment: Just a reference, the default GL_DEPTH_TEXTURE_MODE seems to differ between major OpenGL revisions (2.x/3.x/4.x) and variants (ES 2.x/3.x). In desktop OpenGL 3.x/4.x as well as OpenGL ES 3.x the default is GL_RED. For OpenGL ES 2.x, the default is (I think) GL_LUMINANCE. There seems to be even more shenanigans going on though, please read: http://lists.freedesktop.org/archives/mesa-dev/2013-January/033381.html and http://lists.freedesktop.org/archives/mesa-dev/2012-November/030209.html

Answer (score 1):

```
glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMEMNT0, GL_TEXTURE_2D< pass1_tex[0], 0);
glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_DEPTH_ATTACHMEMNT, GL_TEXTURE_2D< pass1_tex[0], 0);
```

you used the color texture, pass1_tex[0] for both the color and depth buffers

Comment: I wouldn't read too much into his code. The number of arguments to this function are completely wrong and the last parameter looks like the start of a template declaration, but given the way `GL_TEXTURE_2D` is defined and the fact that `>` is absent, it merely evaluates whether the constant `GL_TEXTURE_2D` is greater than the value of `pass_tex [0]`, which is probably a meaningless comparison :)